# Detect if object is lying on the surface or is it lifted into the air?

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, proximity-sensor, gyro, gyroscope

Suppose we have a small box with a circutry and a set of sensors in it. Box is lying on the table, but it is light enough to be lifted into the air.

What I want to achieve is to switch off the circutry in a box if anybody lifts the box, and switch it on back when box is returned to the table.

- Is it possible to detect if object is lying on the surface or is it lifted into the air with just accelerometer(s) and/or gyroscope(s)?
- If not, what set of sensors can reliably do such a job? Proximity sensors? Distance sensors?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A reed relay in the box, and a small magnet buried in the table top.

Comment: @SteveG I don't want (and I can't) modify the surface itself.

Comment: If the surface is reflective enough, you can use a LED+optical sensor (photodiode/phototransistor) in a configuration similar to optical mouses.

Comment: @dim is there a universal solution? I don't know what the surface will be exactly. Ultrasound sensor?

Comment: Yeah, ultrasound would work, for many surfaces.

Comment: Use a microswitch.

Comment: @DmitriyKhudorozhkov I can't guarantee it can work in every situation. Most likely, it depends on how you tune your solution (angle with surface, light beam wideness, sensor sensitivity, ...). Ultrasound may be worth investigating too, but it may be subject to other limitations (surface softness, whatever, ...). In any case, you'll certainly have to try several things.

Comment: Should we consider capacitive touch sense too? Probably won't work on insulating surfaces.

Comment: @pjc50 nope, I'm searching for the universal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accelerometers will tell you if it moves, gyroscopes will tell you if it's rotated. Both of those can tell you if it's picked up - but will probably give you a false positive if someone picks up or bangs the table.

Have you considered a simple contact microswitch on the bottom of the object?

Comment: Yeah a microswitch would work assuming the OP doesn't come back with a new set of constraints but that's what the down vote button is for I guess LOL +1

Comment: @pjc50 well... microswitch would work, but, as all mechanics, it is unreliable. I was hoping to rely on non-movable stuff mostly.

Comment: It is for sure much more reliable than ultrasound, and easier to implement than IR.

Comment: @pjc50 just googles for microswitches - they seem pretty reliable these days. So I may consider them too, thanks.

Comment: @pjc50 I've chosen your answer, as microswitches appear, to my surprise, as the most reliable method. Strange, but thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

An optical reflection  using 5mm IR emitter and detector are most sensitive in the small gap controlled by narrow  beam width and angle.

This pulse "signal" reduces by 2x inverse squared with distance.

Sensitivity with daylight blocking PD is tuned by voltage gain of the Load R and logic level.

- there are Tons of examples of IR proximity methods for < $1

Answer (score 0):

A simple light sensitive device would work in "normal" cases where the surface is opaque and there is ambient light.  Ultrasonic would work regardless of the ambient light, but probably not if the surface is absorbent.  There probably isn't a single, uniformly-acceptable, reasonable-cost solution for all cases